# Where to store the downloadable files of the website hosted in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have design a website where user can upload images and videos. Is it possible the use google cloud storage with compute engine.

Comment: There are a lot of variables here. How are your users uploading the files ? Are you giving them an ftp address, or http, straight from the browser,ssh..etc ? Google cloud storage is ideal for static content. Ultimately, the users upload files to your server, which is not but a directory/folder on the disk. That directory can be rsync'd to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, so periodically your folder will be sync'd with the bucket. If you can provide some background on the Webserver type and uploading method, then I can provide some more insight

Comment: can we connect compute engine to google cloud storage as we connect server to SAN storage

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use any of google cloud component with each other.
This must be done while creating your instance you need to select the other google component which you want to use with the instance.

In Console while creating new instance, more options you will see 
ACCESS Security---Project access and then select which component you want to use with an instance and assign the permission level.

Same will be also possible with gcloud compute while creating instance

I hope this will be helpful.